# Adding to columns based on length

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a ListView with two columns, Boxes and Files. I'm adding items to a list of strings, and then populating the ListView with that list of strings. I want to make it so all items that are 8 characters long go into the Boxes column and all items that are 9 characters go into the Files column. So far, I've tried to iterate through using a for loop and utilize an if else statement to add the items, but I seem to be doing something wrong. Here's my current code:

```
public void PopulateItemsList()
    {
        BoxAndFileList.Items.Clear();
        ScanIdBox.Text = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < BoxNumberRepository._boxAndFileList.Count; i++)
        {
            var item = BoxNumberRepository._boxAndFileList.Item[i];
            if (item.Length == 8)
            {
                BoxAndFileList.Items.Insert(0, item);
            }
            else
            {
                BoxAndFileList.Items.Insert(1, item);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm iterating through my list (_boxAndFileList) and trying to utilize Insert() to insert items into the specific index of the columns (Boxes is 0, Files is 1). I can clearly see that Item is a legitimate property of a string list, yet VS keeps saying that list contains no definition of it. How can I go about doing this? And also, I haven't received outside feedback on this way of doing things yet, so if there's a better way, please let me know.

Edit: BoxNumberRepository is a class that news up a list called _boxAndFileList. Code below:

```
public class BoxNumberRepository : Scan_Form
    {
        public static List<string> _boxAndFileList = new List<string>();

        public void AddItem(string item)
        {
            _boxAndFileList.Add(item);
        }

        public void Delete(string item)
        {
            _boxAndFileList.Remove(item);
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> GetAllItems()
        {
            return _boxAndFileList;
        }
    }
```

Thanks to Alessandro D'Andria for that suggestion. That was correct. However, all the items are still just adding to the first column, even if they're 9 characters. How can I get 9 character items to add to the second column?

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: WinForms (put it in the tags. sorry that i didn't make it more obvious in the OP)

Comment: @paqogomez don't you see the `tags`?

Comment: It was very obvious.  My mistake

Comment: You said you want to put 2 kinds of item in separated columns, but what about row? in each loop you can insert only 1 item at a column but a row in your listview has 2 columns? In fact your code insert each item on separated rows (not columns).

Comment: What does the BoxNumberRepository class look like?

Comment: If `_boxAndFileList` is a `List<T>` then no property Items just [i].

Comment: Please define `BoxNumberRepository` and `_boxAndFileList`

Comment: It looks to me you are inserting all the items in the same list. Some of them at position 0 and others at position 1, but they all end up in the same list? I am assuming BoxAndFileList.Items is a List.

Comment: All the items first go to _boxAndFileList, a list of strings. Then this method gets called, where I'm hoping to iterate through the items and add all the 8 character items to column 1 and all the 9 character items to column 2 of my ListView BoxAndFileList.

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx for List<T>

Comment: You need to add both box and file to the list item at the same time.  Something like the answer i posted should work for you.

Comment: Man, that was a good bit of code and nothin! :D

Comment: Sorry. I've been busy with personal things, and I don't yet code as my primary profession, so I haven't had a chance to check this until today. I'll be trying out your solution now and will let you know the outcome.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria I've reviewed that msdn page, which is why I was trying to use the Item property. I was mistaken about the usage, so thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Thanks for asking about the index problem.  All fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are having is that you have to add both the `box` and `file` to the `list item` at the same time.

EDIT: Changed cartesian product to a left outer join.

EDIT: Added comments and fixed a syntax bug

```
private List<string> _boxAndFileList = new List<string> { "12345678", "123456789", "1234", "123456778" };
public void PopulateItemsList()
{
    //clear the list
    BoxAndFileList.Items.Clear();
    //add the labels to the top of the listbox
    BoxAndFileList.Columns.Add("Boxes");
    BoxAndFileList.Columns.Add("Files");
    //set the view of the list to a details view (important if you try to display images)
    BoxAndFileList.View = View.Details;
    //clear scan id box
    ScanIdBox.Text = string.Empty;

    //get all the items whos length are 8 as well as a unique id (index)
    var boxes = _boxAndFileList.Where(b => b.Length == 8).Select((b, index) => new { index, b }).ToList();
    //get all the items whos length are NOT 8 as well as a unique id (index)
    var files = _boxAndFileList.Where(f => f.Length != 8).Select((f, index) => new { index, f }).ToList();

    //join them together on their unique ids so that you get info on both sides.
    var interim = (from f in files
                   join b in boxes on f.index equals b.index into bf
                   from x in bf.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   select new { box = (x == null ? String.Empty : x.b), file = f.f });
    //the real trick here is that you have to add 
    //to the listviewitem of type string[] in order to populate the second, third, or more column.
    //I'm just doing this in linq, but var x = new ListViewItem(new[]{"myBox", "myFile"}) would work the same
    var fileboxes = interim.Select(x => new ListViewItem(new []{ x.box, x.file})).ToArray();
    //add the array to the listbox
    BoxAndFileList.Items.AddRange(fileboxes);
    //refresh the listbox
    BoxAndFileList.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: I've got to admit, that's quite a complex piece of code that I'm having a hard time following. So far, VS is complaining that 'string' contains no definition for 'index'. It doesn't look like there's any other property that can give me the index for string without another error popping up about the types in the joint clause being incorrect.

Comment: You are correct! Damn.. that was in a previous edit.  The index is in an override of select.  Let me fix that now

Comment: ok.. fixed the bad edit and added comments.  Hopefully this will clarify the whole issue.  Dont let the `linq` confuse you.  Your real issue is just using the `string[]` overload of `ListViewItem` and the fact that you need to add both box and file together to the `ListBoxItem` instead of one at a time.

Comment: Good. This gets me very close. Thank you for your patience and thorough commenting. I haven't done any linq yet, hence my confusion. When I first add an 8 character item, it doesn't add anything. If I add a 9 character item, it adds it to both columns, and then after that, works properly. I'll debug from here to try and get my head around some of this new stuff.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707419/pad-the-left-or-right-sides-of-a-linq-join-to-be-the-same-number-of-rows.  I asked this question to fix the right and left problem you are having.  The answer was a pretty good one, but it might challenge you as it uses an extension method. :D Good Luck!

Comment: Challenge, I don't mind. I just hope if I have questions concerning said challenge, someone would answer me in a similar fashion as you have on this post: thoroughly and patiently.

Answer (score 0):

Your _boxAndFileList is a `List<string>` so you should be declare item as `string` type instead `var` type:

```
string item = BoxNumberRepository._boxAndFileList.Item[i];
```

All your code should be like this:

```
public void PopulateItemsList()
{
    BoxAndFileList.Items.Clear();
    ScanIdBox.Text = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < BoxNumberRepository._boxAndFileList.Count; i++)
    {
        string item = BoxNumberRepository._boxAndFileList.Item[i];
        if (item.Length == 8)
        {
            BoxAndFileList.Items.Insert(0, item);
        }
        else
        {
            BoxAndFileList.Items.Insert(1, item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, the OP doesn't even seem to know what his code does. He wants each item to be on separated columns but this code inserts each item on separated rows. He might have gone to sleep. So let's wait him to give more clarification.

Comment: Not sure if you intended this, but this sounds pretty condescending. I am a noob, and still very much in the learning process. I know what I want my code to do, but am unsure of how to get my code to do it. I know the columns have an index number, and so I tried to push to those columns using their index number. Whether that's right or wrong, I'm unsure. That's why I'm here asking people that hopefully do know.

Comment: Dont let @KingKing get to you, he's a great developer and tells it like it is, sometimes with too little tact. ;)