# Pad the left or right sides of a linq join to be the same number of rows

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

My goal is to create a list that is the same number of rows on the right or left, irrespective of if the left column or right column is shorter than the other.

Consider these two queries:

```
var result1 = (from f in list2
               join b in list1 on f.index equals b.index into bf
               from x in bf.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new { box = (x == null ? String.Empty : x.b), file = f.f });

var result2 = (from b in list1
              join f in list2 on b.index equals f.index into bf
              from x in bf.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new { l1 = x.f, l2 = (x == null ? String.Empty : b.b) });
```

One tests for null on the list1 and fills in an empty string, the other tests for null on list2 and fills in an empty string.

I'd like to find an example where both can happen.  The order is not important, just that every value or empty string on the left, has a value or empty string on the right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you need a version of the `IEnumerable.Zip` extension method that doesn't stop when the shorter list has reached its end:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> ZipAll<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> list1,
                                                           IEnumerable<T> list2,
                                                           Func<T, T, TResult> zipper,
                                                           T defaultValue = default(T))
{
    using (var enum1 = list1.GetEnumerator())
    {
        using (var enum2 = list2.GetEnumerator())
        {

            bool valid1, valid2;
            do
            {
                valid1 = enum1.MoveNext();
                valid2 = enum2.MoveNext();
                if (valid1 || valid2)
                {
                    var item1 = valid1 ? enum1.Current : defaultValue;
                    var item2 = valid2 ? enum2.Current : defaultValue;

                    yield return zipper(item1, item2);
                }
            }
            while (valid1 || valid2);

        }
    }
}
```

..and then:

```
var result = list1.ZipAll(list2, (l1, l2) => new { l1, l2 }, string.Empty);
```

Comment: Excellent use of the extension.  I was trying to do it all in linq, but this is a sweet solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Yep, extension methods are great :)

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your problem correctly, then you are almost there where you want to:

- convert your result to List of anonymous items
- select all items to new List>
- put l1 and l2 to the new List of Lists
- you need to flatten the result with SelectMany

The extended code:

```
var result= (from f in list2
               join b in list1 on f.index equals b.index into bf
               from x in bf.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new { l1 = (x == null ? String.Empty : x.b), l2 = f.f })
               .ToList().Select(li => new List<List<string>> 
                                            { 
                                                new List<string> 
                                                { 
                                                    li.l1, 
                                                    li.l2 
                                                } 
                                            }).ToList()
                                            .SelectMany (li => li).ToList();
```

This gives List containing List of string objects like this:

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly for one side, but not the other.  I'll update my post with an example for the other side.

Comment: My post was too complicated i think.  I have simplified it greatly, let me know if you think i should add any bits back in.